# Convert xml to json which one variable already having json format value in c#

Tags: json, .net, xml, c#-3.0

I have XML like

```
 "<root><name>john</name><info>{\"age\":25,\"city\":\"NYC\"}</info></root>"
```

When I used JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)

It's showing below output

```
 
{
"root":{
"name":"john",
"info":"{\"age\":25,\"city\":\"NYC\"}"
}
}
```

But I want this in below format

```
{

"root":{
"name":"john",
"info":{
"age":25,
"city":"NYC"
}
}
```

I have tried multiple things but result are same

Comment: I wanted this in c#

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it into a `JObject`, then replace that property with a parsed `JObject` of itself

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xDoc);
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
obj["root"]["info"] = JObject.Parse(obj["root"]["info"].Value<string>());
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VYQa4h)